# Trying to download new Yakuake skins on my Arch/Gnome installation, but cannot

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, gnome, proxy

Currently I am using Arch Linux with a Gnome Desktop Environment. Now I have chosen to use Yakuake as my terminal. I'd like to use other skins that other people have put up online for my terminal. However when I try to get 'hot new skins', this is what happens.

[image]

I must inform people that I have an http proxy. This maybe the primary reason why I cannot connect to http://kde-look.org/index.php?xsortmode=high&page=0&xcontentmode=87.

As an alternative, is there a way I can get skins on Yakuake offline by downloading the skins from the website? This will only be a valid answer if I cannot download my skin over the proxy and the port I have as of now.